# How to exclude files from bundling in aurelia.json

Tags: aurelia

I'd like to prevent src/config.js to be bundled in scripts/app-bundle.js

I saw that previously the syntax was:

```
 "bundles": {
          "dist/app-build": {
              "includes": [
                  "[**/*.js]",
                  "**/*.html!text",
                  "**/*.css!text",
                  "cloneya",
                  "dexie",
                  "jquery",
                  "jquery-ui",
                  "medium-editor-webpack",
                  "moment",
                  "polymer/mutationobservers",
                  "safe-json-stringify"
              ],
              excludes: [
                  "config.js" // So our wildcard globbing doesn't include this config file
              ],
...
```

However the new syntax is different: aurelia.json:

```
  "bundles": [
            {
                "name": "app-bundle.js",
                "source": [
                    "[**/*.js]",
                    "**/*.{css,html}"
                ],
                "excludes" : [
                    "**/config.js"
                ]
            },
```

My temptative 'exclude' statement doesn't do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is actually given on the GitHub page: https://github.com/aurelia/cli

> Optionally, you can define an exclude list by setting the source
>   property to be an object containing both an include and exclude array
>   of patterns. This is helpful when you're trying to define multiple
>   bundles from your source code.
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "app-bundle.js",
>   "source": {
>     "include": [
>       "[**/*.js]",
>       "**/*.{css,html}"
>     ],
>     "exclude": [
>       "**/sub-module/**/*",
>     ]
>   }
> },
> {
>   "name": "sub-module-bundle.js",
>   "source": [
>     "**/sub-module/**/*",
>   ]
> }
> ```

Make sure you have version > 0.19.0

Comment: actually, this would be the better reference imho:  https://aurelia.io/docs/cli/cli-bundler/basics#bundling-and-code-splitting